# Train effect with jQuery ui Slide effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-slide-effects

I want to make interface that when I click the button, the registration form will slide.

In the effect similar to "train" one car is gone the next come.

But I found it difficult with jQuery Slide effect because it create "wrapper for sliding effect"

And the result is

http://jsbin.com/aququs/18

Source Code:

http://jsbin.com/aququs/18/edit

I wonder if I choosen the right tool to done something like that. Maybe I should use only "animate" jQuery function ? And try operate with "margins" ?

Thank you very much for solution to my problem

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like: http://jsbin.com/iculap/1 ?